# Use of `if( ... = ... )` in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
insert into foo_table (fname, lname, number)
values ('John', 'Doe', if(123 = 456));
```

For the above MySQL query, can somebody kindly explain what the `if(123 = 456)` is doing? I currently struggle to see an if statement without a body (i.e. `if(condition){ // do something }`);

Comment: It would insert a record with the values `('John', 'Doe', 0)`. As for the reason to have this, you will need to ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: It's a syntax error. The `IF()` function requires 3 arguments. The first argument is a condition expression. If it's true the function returns the second argument, otherwise it returns the third argument.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is syntactically not correct as per mysql version 8, The syntactically correct query is `insert into foo_table (fname, lname, number) values ('John', 'Doe', if(123 = 456,1,2))`. This will insert 1 if the condition (123 =456) is true, otherwise it will insert 2.